# Easy way to create single element Json C#

Tags: c#, json

I know that that could be easily written by myself but probably there is a better way to do something like that. I need an easy way (static method) to create JSON with one element.
Something like that one

```
OneElementJson("name", "value")
```

and have something like that

```
{"name":"value"}
```

as result. The name should be always a string, value in most cases also string but overloading for tables list will be nice.

Comment: Why not use `System.Text.Json`? (i.e. `JsonSerializer.Serialize(new {name: "value"})`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is the simple string then Serge's example is neat and simple.

If you want a more generic way of doing this then use var or Dynamic ojects and any of the JSON serializers. Here's an example from .NET Core:

Using var:

```
var thing2 = new { name = "value" };

string jsonString2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(thing2);
Console.WriteLine(jsonString2);
```

Using Dynamic:

```
dynamic thing = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject(); 
thing.name = "value";

string jsonString = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(thing);
Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
```

The result is: `{"name":"value"}`

Answer (score 0):

I just created a library for you in a minute

```
public string GetOneElementJson<T> (string name, T value) 
{
     var val= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    return "{\"" + name + "\":" +  val + "}";
}
```

test

```
  var json=GetOneElementJson("name", "value");

var json = GetOneElementJson("doubleArray", new double[] { 1.2, 3.3, 4 });

 var json = GetOneElementJson("stringArray", new string[] { "one", "two", "three" });

  var jObject =JObject.Parse(json);
```

outputs

```
{"name":"value"}

{"doubleArray":[1.2,3.3,4]}

{"stringArray":["one","two","three"]}
```

Comment: Yes, until name or value contains a `"`. Also worth noting that at the end of the question is says value might be a list sometimes, which I guess means OP wants json like `{"x":[1,2,3]}` rather than like `{"x":"System.Int32[]"}` - how about an overload that takes an IEnumerable?

Comment: @CaiusJard it is just   a joke,  I had nothing else to do. OP doesn' t need any library. Something like J sonSerializer.Serialize will do this job in one line.

Comment: @CaiusJard I updated my library. Thanks for reminding

Comment: (Not my downvote btw but I'm thinking it's probably a wheel not worth reinventing because of all the edge cases that will start coming out )